# Ask Confirmation Before Delete files/directories

Tags: linux

I'm facing many issues and lost many files because of `rm -rf`.

If I use `rm -rfi xxx.xx`, then it promote confirmation. But I forget/unable to give `-i` command when I'm using.

Is any other way to provide default `-i` or

I need like , Whenever I use `rm` , it must promote confirmation.

Any idea?

Comment: set an alias for rm which provides `-i`... `alias rm='rm -i'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add an alias

`alias rm="rm -i"`

This ensures that each time you use `rm` it is replaced with `rm -i` so that each time it asks for a confirmation

If you are using a bash, you can add the alias to the `.bashrc` file so that you need not add the alias each time.

```
$ rm test.c
rm: remove regular file `test.c'? y
```

Answer (score 2):

Make alias for rm command:

```
alias rm='rm -i'
```

Answer (score 1):

Create [alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(command)) for `rm`-command:

```
alias rm="rm -i"
```